# Как правильно организовать работу с базой данных

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-room

Довольно неудобная ситуация. Есть класс Weather, с помощью него я работаю с апи, предоставляющий прогноз погоды. Использую retrofit. Класс получился вот такой:

```
public class Weather  {  
    public class WeatherValue {
        double temp;
        double humidity;
    }

    public class WeatherIcon {
        String icon;
    }

    @SerializedName("main")
    private WeatherValue weatherTemp;

    @SerializedName("weather")
    private List<WeatherIcon> weatherIcon;

    @SerializedName("dt")
    private long time;

    // Getters...
}
```

Не очень удобно, т.к. в полях есть объекты внутренних классов, но все работает. Теперь необходимо с помощью Room сохранять список объектов Weather в базу данных. Неудобство в том, что, на сколько я понимаю, Room не понимает как работать с объектами, ему нужны только примитивные типы. Поэтому с этим классом он работать не сможет.

Получается, что для сохранения в базу данных прогноза погоды необходим примерно вот такой класс:

```
public class Weather  {
    @PrimaryKey
    int id;
    double temp;
    double humidity;
    String iconUrl;
    long time;
}
```

Как в таком случае правильно поступить? Первое что приходит на ум - создать оба эти класса. Когда работаю с апи - пользоваться первым, а когда буду сохранять в базу данных - трансформировать его во второй класс и уже его сохранять. Звучит криво, поэтому прошу совета. Как правильно организовать это?

Comment: возможно вам нужно [воспользоваться @Embedded](https://startandroid.ru/ru/27-course/architecture-components/530-urok-6-room-entity.html) (раздел Вложенные объекты), которые предоставляет API Room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно так и надо сделать - создавать отдельные классы для разных слоёв приложения. Отдельный класс для сетевого слоя, отдельный для БД, отдельный для отображения в UI. Так у вас будут классы в которых не придётся идти на разные ухищрения для работы во всех слоях, они не будут перегружены множеством аннотаций и будут в нужном для слоя формате.

Comment: думаю в случае Room проще решить через `@TypeConverter` и/или `@Embedded` для слоя сервера и ViewModel для слоя UI, чем разная структура данных каждого слоя.